# Bitbucket ssh Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, git-bash, bitbucket.org

I'm using ssh to access git repository on bitbucket.org.
Suddenly I can no longer connect to it. Haven't installed anything or did any changes to the settings.

```
$ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org   

OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007                                    
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/home/.ssh/config    
debug1: Applying options for bitbucket.org                                   
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.                
debug1: Connection established.                                              
debug1: identity file /c/home/.ssh/id_rsa type 1          
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3     
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*                                      
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0                         
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6                             
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent                                                
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received                                            
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none                         
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none                         
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent                     
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP                                  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent                                        
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY                                  
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.          
debug1: Found key in /c/home/.ssh/known_hosts:1           
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct                                    
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent                                                
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS                                           
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received                                            
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent                                        
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received                                     
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset by peer" means that the remote end of the TCP connection closed. So the remote SSH server decided to drop your connection, or it crashed or something like that. It's not possible to tell from the SSH trace exactly what the reason was. The connection was dropped before performing authentication, so it's not a simple authentication problem. You should contact the server operators for assistance.

Comment: But I couldn't see any issues with bitbucket, besides my colleagues were able to connect...